# How to reverse the selected record in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to reverse the record i select and show it.

for example, i have this table in my database:

```
 -----------------------------------
|   id  |   entry   |   created_at  |
 -----------------------------------
|   1   |     A     |     15:00     |
|   2   |     B     |     16:00     |
|   3   |     C     |     18:00     |
 -----------------------------------
```

I want to select and show it from the latest created_at

I try to select it by this code:

```
$users  = DB::table('entry as e')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'e.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
                ->select('users.name as name', 'e.*')->where('e.id_user', '=', Auth::id())
                ->where(latest('created_at'))
                ->get();
```

But it's not working.

Comment: `
order by created_at desc`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $users  = DB::table('entry as e')
             ->leftJoin('users', 'e.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
             ->select('users.name as name', 'e.*')
             ->where('e.id_user', '=',Auth::id())
             ->orderBy('e.created_at', 'DESC')
             ->get();
```

specify which table has create_at column if first table then e.create_at or if second table then users.created_at

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `created_at` on both tables. You'll have to qualify it:

```php
$users = DB::table('entry as e')
           ->leftJoin('users', 'e.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
           ->select('users.name as name', 'e.*')
           ->where('e.id_user', Auth::id())
           ->latest('e.created_at')
           ->get();
```